# Cannot pass and loop data with CodeIgniter Jade template engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, pug

I have a problem with passing and looping data with Jade Template Engine. I've tried to implement **Jade** with **Code Igniter** (PHP framework version 3), of course it worked perfectly, I can extends layout, create file with jade , using jade syntax. Unfortunately I don't know how to pass the data which I have gotten from database to the jade view. More seriously I really don't know how to loop data as a json with Jade.

I have tried with the code below but it was not worked.

PHP Code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
//https://github.com/ci-jade/ci-jade
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    use Jade;

      public function index()
      {
        $this->settings([
      'cache' => TRUE
    ]);

        $this->view('myview', [
      'title' => 'My Jade View',
      'authors' => array(json_encode($this->user_model()->result()))

    ]);
      }

    public function user_model()
    {
      return $this->db->get('user');
    }
}
```

Jade : myview

```
extends  layout
block script
  script(type='text/javascript')
    document.write('Hello M');
block content
  #{authors}
  h1 Hello I am using jade
  each user in authors
    li=user.user_name
```

You, see there was no error and also there were no data also.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [ci-jade](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/ci-jade)(I'm assuming that's the one you are using) documentation, it seems like you are implementing it the wrong way. The documentation shows that you have to call `$this->load->library('jade')` to use it(this goes for all codeigniter libraries). You also have to call `$this->load->vars()` to pass variables to the views. After loading the library you will be able to use its methods by calling `$this->jade->...()`.

For more information on using codeigniter libraries take a look at [this](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/libraries.html).

Comment: Thanks for you replying. So I have follow your code and it shown the errors : 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Jade::$jade_view_path

Filename: libraries/Jade.php

Line Number: 63

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\libraries\Jade.php
Line: 63
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\jade\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: @Samphors If the previous problem in your question was solved by my answer, please mark it as an answer. If you run into something new, please ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right, maybe I will ask other question. I've met an error as I've shown you.

Comment: @Samphors The problem is that you can post an error, but it really don't know what could've caused it without looking at any code, and posting code inside a comment just makes a mess.